# Maven ignores local default repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I have two Spring Boot projets. Project B depends on project A.
Both are using maven to manage their dependencies.

The problem is i cannot run project B since Intellij can't import project A classes and give me this error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project B: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project A:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The 
following artifacts could not be resolved: X:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, Y:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, 
Z:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT: was not found in https://jitpack.io during a previous attempt. This 
failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not
```

Of course all these artifacts are in the default local repository, and in the XML settings file i didn't specify any repository path other than the default one **( ${user.home}/.m2/repository )**.
So it should search for the dependecies in the local .m2 repo instead of checking in remote repo **( jitpack.io )**

This is weird because these projects works absolutely fine on another device.

I tried multiple solutions :

- invalidate the cache and restart
- force the project to reimport it dependencies
- delete the pom.xml and recreate it
- tried with a new project C which also fails
- checked the settings and the repo's are on point
- deleted the .idea file
- updated the maven repo's index
- deleted the whole maven folder
- reinstalled new versions for both Intellij and maven

It seems like nothing is working.
Any solutions ?

For the errors i got two differents :
When i try to build the projet with intellij i get multiple errors for classes which aren't recognized, example :

```
java: package A.common.exception does not exist
```

I get the other one when i try to build it in shell with "mvn clean install", here is the complete stacktrace :

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oksymed-connect-common: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.oksymed.connect:oksymed-connect-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The followin
g artifacts could not be resolved: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-elastic:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-mongo:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-mongoElastic:jar:1.2
.1-SNAPSHOT: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://jitpack.io during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not 
reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project oksymed-connect-common: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.oksymed.connect:oksymed
-connect-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-elastic:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-mongo:jar:
1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-mongoElastic:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://jitpack.io during a previous attempt. This failure was cache
d in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.oksymed.connect:oksymed-connect-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The followi
ng artifacts could not be resolved: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-elastic:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-mongo:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-mongoElastic:jar:1.
2.1-SNAPSHOT: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://jitpack.io during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not
 reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-elastic:jar:1.
2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-mongo:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-mongoElastic:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://jitpack.io during a prev
ious attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:357)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-elastic:jar:1.2.
1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-mongo:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT, com.lfk:lfk-mongoElastic:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://jitpack.io during a previo
us attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: com.lfk:lfk-common:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://jitpack.io during a previous attempt. This failure was 
cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of jitpack.io has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException (DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact (DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: Is the problem IntelliJ or Maven? Invoke Maven from the command line. If the build completes successfully, you've isolated the issue to IntelliJ.

Comment: Please show the full pom files and the whole log output including error messages... why do you use https://jitpack.io ? Have you confgured that in your pom file? Why not using a repository manager ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Why is the first question relevant? It's a perfectly valid repository.

Comment: Actually the problem is the same with command line

Comment: Yes i added jitpack.io for the needs of the project ( in pom.xml )

Comment: The problem is simply because your build does not work...and tries to check jitpack which means your configuration in your build is simply wrong... Always use a repository manager never rely on external resources...

Comment: @khmarbaise Please... You are muddying the issue by trying to suggest best practices, when what they are trying attempting to achieve is already *perfectly valid*. "*Do X valid thing instead of Y valid thing*" is **not** an explanation as to why X valid thing doesn't work.

Comment: If it would be perfectly "valid"  it would work but it does not... So there must be something wrong with the "valid" ...